# Typescript generic array is being cast to any[]?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write some generic array utility functions, but when I try calling one from another, the compiler seems to cast the generic to `any[]` and gives me this error:

```
Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

My code:

```
type UnwrapArray<T extends any[]> = T extends (infer G)[] ? G : never;

function removeFromArray<T extends any[]>(
  array: T,
  value: UnwrapArray<T>
) {
  return array.filter(other => other !== value);
}

function toggleArrayValue<T extends any[]>(array: T, value: UnwrapArray<T>): T {
  if(array.includes(value)) {
    return removeFromArray<T>(array, value);
  } else {
    return [...array, value];
  }
}
```

The specific lines giving me trouble are these:

```
return removeFromArray<T>(array, value);
```

And

```
return [...array, value];
```

I've found I can add `as T` to a bunch of stuff and it will compile successfully, but it seems like the compiler should figure this out on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assume `T` extends `any[]` will mean `T` is an array, and any new array will be assignable to `T`. This is not true.

Consider the following:

```
const myArr = Object.assign([1, 2, 3], {
    extraProp : 1
})

toggleArrayValue(myArr, 1).extraProp // ts says this should be here where is my extraProp
```

`extends any[]` is the lower bound on what `T` can be, but it can be anything that inherits array (or a tuple but that is another can of worms of why this can't work)

I am not sure at least from your sample code why you need `T` to be an array. You can express what you are trying to do without this:

```
function removeFromArray<T>(
    array: T[],
    value: T
) {
    return array.filter(other => other !== value);
}

function toggleArrayValue<T>(array: T[], value: T): T[] {
    if (array.includes(value)) {
        return removeFromArray<T>(array, value);
    } else {
        return [...array, value];
    }
}
```

Maybe your actual code is more complex, if so post that (maybe in a different question) and we can see if we can find a better solution than an unsafe type assertion.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly and your explanation makes a lot of sense.